# Does a CF template continue to run even if the browser is closed?

Tags: coldfusion

Apologies if this is a blatantly newbie question, but I'm suddenly unsure of the answer.

I am running several large tasks that runs through database records with `<cfloop>`. It can take several hours to run.

If the CF template is 'executed' (basically its .cfm page is visited in the browser - not by a scheduled task), but the browser is closed mid-cylce, will the template continue to run on the server until its completed? Or does it abort/exit the template at the point the window is closed?

Comment: It will continue to run

Comment: Yes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631486/what-happens-when-we-refresh-a-web-page (ignore the "refresh" part) FWIW, you can test it yourself. Simulate a long running script with a loop. Have it log to a file on each iteration, then sleeps for 50ms. Load the script in your browser. Then cancel the request after a few seconds and check the log.

Comment: *It can take several hours to run.* You should rethink your approach. First, determine if looping is really necessary, it often is not. Second, if it is, split the work into batches of X records and run it as a one time scheduled task. Have the task process X records each time. Then call itself again until there are not more records to process. Requires a little more work than a loop, but is much more robust.

Comment: Thanks @MattBusche and Leigh - always very helpful and kind to my questions :)

Comment: @volumeone - Welcome. Since the exact question in the title was already asked and answered, I am voting to close this one as a duplicate. That said... it seems like your real question is how to handle a large, potentially long running process. I am curious about the looping in the current process. Looping is often the least desirable approach for processing large amounts of data, and can often (though not always) be refactored into a faster, more efficient set based approach. Might want to open a separate thread about that specific question.

Comment: The looping runs because it sends a <cfmail> with each iteration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will continue to run. When your browser makes the request it is asking the web server (IIS, Apache, etc...) for a CF page, the web server is then asking the CF engine and the CF engine starts processing the template. Once finished processing, the CF engine sends the response to the web server which sends it to your browser. From this, you can see that the CF engine does not know that you closed the browser.