# Page_Load run Button_Click

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have a web-part in SharePoint 2013 which adds the new items from excel. The web-part contains upload control, buttons and textbox. I choose the document from upload control and click the button to load items in SP, if it was successfull I see "Successfull" in textbox or "Not successfull" in another way.

**My problem:** if i refresh page with web-part, textbox still contains the old text, but i want to see it empty after every refresh.

I try to use Page.IsPostBack, but I think I didn't properly use it.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    textbox1.Text = "";
}

protected void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        return;
    if(!upload.HasFile)
    {
        textbox1.Text += "You didn't choose an Excel file";
        return;
    }
       ...
}

<asp:Button ID="btn3" runat="server" OnClick="btn3_Click" Text="Add Items" />
```

Comment: I refresh the page not by code, using internet browser.

Comment: `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` will prevent exactly that - it makes sure that the textbox is assigned empty string only on the first page load, and not on the refreshes. Why do you use it, if you want the opposite behavior?

Comment: I use Page.IsPostBack == false because as i understand it means that it's non client - server answer. And refresh of the page don't need server answer.

Comment: Nope, `IsPostBack` means something different. It indicates whether you are on the first load of the page or on the subsequent load after user did some interaction

Comment: And the browser will do a server request on refresh again, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1631486/728795) for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such case, you can implement a special code block to detect browser refresh as

```
private bool refreshState;
private bool isRefresh;

protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{
    object[] AllStates = (object[])savedState;
    base.LoadViewState(AllStates[0]);
    refreshState = bool.Parse(AllStates[1].ToString());
    if (Session["ISREFRESH"] != null && Session["ISREFRESH"] != "")
        isRefresh = (refreshState == (bool)Session["ISREFRESH"]);
}

protected override object SaveViewState()
{
    Session["ISREFRESH"] = refreshState;
    object[] AllStates = new object[3];
    AllStates[0] = base.SaveViewState();
    AllStates[1] = !(refreshState);
    return AllStates;
}
```

In the button click you can do it as

```
protected void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isRefresh == false)
        {
            Insert Code here
        }
}
```

Comment: I have an exception that i should set enableSessionState  = true in config file or using page directive. I can't edit config file then  i add <%@ Page Language="C#" enableSessionState="true" %>  in my .ascx file and have another exception : unknown directive "page"